# kotlin dagger retrofit field injection

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

When trying to inject field variables using dagger I'm getting null. Here are the files. Some are in Java and some in Kotlin

App.java

```
   public class App extends DaggerApplication{


    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        NetworkModule::class,
        ApplicationModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
        ))
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<TBApplication> {


    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): AppComponent.Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

NetworkModule.kt

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
        }
        return builder.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseApi.SITE_ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit
    }


}
```

// Repository where injection should be done

```
    class Repository {

        private var examsService: BlogExamsService

        @Inject
        var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

        init {
            // retrofit is null here
            examsService = retrofit?.create(BlogExamsService::class.java)!!
        }
   }
```

Comment: you're not injecting `Repository`, you could make it part of the dependency graph and provide it from a module

Answer (score 2):

Field injection won't work as you do not run `inject()` method.

To make it work with your approach you should call in you `Repository` class:

`App.self.getComponent().inject(this)`

Where:

`self` is `static` instance of your application

`getComponent()` public getter for `ApplicationComponent`

**Though I would not recommend it in your case, it is a misuse of DI framework.**

You should create `RepositoryModule` and `@Provide` instance of `Repository` the same as you have done with `NetworkModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Repository` to:

```
class Repository {

    private var examsService: BlogExamsService

    @Inject
    constructor(retrofit: Retrofit) {
        examsService = retrofit.create(BlogExamsService::class.java)!!
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm creating instance of repository somewhere else in code. Any idea about why field injection won't work ?

Comment: Do not create the instance yourself, inject it using `@Inject internal lateinit var repository: Repository`